# Laravel json return 404

Tags: php, json, laravel

I try to get list of users addresses on dropdown but i get `404` error on network also when i test it by url it returns `404 Page Not Found`

## Logic

1. User can have many address
2. Each address has `user_id` column in `addresses` table (I can get them from address table by their user_id)

## What I need?

1- Select user in dropdown

2- Show his/her addresses in other dropdown

My controller:

```
public function getAddressList($user_id)
{
  $address = Address::where('user_id',$user_id)->get();
  return response()->json($address);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/getAddressList/{user_id}','OrderController@getAddressList');
```

Blade:

```
// Select boxes
<div class="row bg-danger mb-20" style="padding: 7px;">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        {{ Form::label('user_id', 'Buyer') }}
                        <select name="user_id" class="form-control">
                            <option class="form-control" value="">Select user</option>
                             @foreach($users as $user)
                              <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        {{ Form::label('address_id', 'Buyer Address') }}
                        <select name="address_id" class="form-control">
                            <option class="form-control" value="">Select Address</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                  </div>


//Javascript codes
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[name="user_id"]').on('change', function() {
    var userID = $(this).val();
    if(userID) {
      $.ajax({
          url: '{{ url('getAddressList') }}/'+encodeURI(userID),
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          success:function(data) {
          $('select[name="address_id"]').empty();
          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
              $('select[name="address_id"]').append('<option class="form-control" value="'+ value['id'] +'">'+ value['address'] +'</option>');
              });
          },
      });
    }else{
      $('select[name="address_id"]').empty();
    }
  });
});
</script>


PS: if i visit: `http://domain.dev/getAddressList/1` i get 404 Page not fount as well as inspect network tab
```

Comment: Try replacing `$user_id` with `getAddressList(Request $request)` and access the `$user_id` as `$request->user_id`

Comment: @linktoahref and my url (route)?

Comment: Just try changing your function signature, route will remain same

Comment: @linktoahref not sure if i did it right or no `public function getAddressList(Request $request)
    {
        $address = Address::where('user_id', '=', $request->user_id)->get();
        return $address;
    }` but the result is `404`

Comment: Does the route have any prefix? or is there any other route definition that starts with `/getAddressList/` of type `GET`?

Comment: do one thing please, load your page in browser, right click the page and click show page source and post it here

Comment: @linktoahref damn! :)) it was under group route! thanks dude

Comment: @linktoahref please share answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route definition

```
Route::get('/getAddressList/{user_id}','OrderController@getAddressList');
```

must have been placed under group definition with some `prefix`.

Rectifying the route definition placement would resolve your issue.

With respect to the comments, you could revert back your controller method signature to

```
public function getAddressList($user_id) {}
```